# Поставить точку на картинке

Tags: javascript

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Подскажите, есть к примеру картинка на странице. Как поставить при помощи курсора точку (круг, флаг без разницы) и записать их координаты в массив. Можно ли это сделать при помощи js?

Comment: да. С помощью canvas + Event "click". Тут про кэнвэс https://habr.com/ru/post/111385/

Comment: @Node_pro, спасибо, прочту!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const coords = [];
const container = document.querySelector('.container-image');

container.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const point = e.target.closest('.container-point');

  if (point) return removePoint(point);

  const x = e.offsetX;
  const y = e.offsetY;

  coords.push({
    x: x,
    y: y
  });
  container.appendChild(createPoint(x, y));

  console.log(coords);
}, false);

const createPoint = (x, y) => {
  const node = document.createElement('div');

  node.classList.add('container-point');

  node.style.left = `${x}px`;
  node.style.top = `${y}px`;

  return node;
}

const removePoint = (node) => {
  const index = [...container.children].indexOf(node) - 1;

  coords.splice(index, 1);

  node.remove();

  console.log(coords);
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.container-point {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-image">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/300/300" alt="#">
</div>
```

Comment: Если повторно кликнуть на поставленную точку, новая точка уходит на верхний левый угол) Можно например хранить offsetLeft / Top картинки вне клика. А при клике, как координаты брать `e.pageX - offsetLeft`

Comment: Спасибо. А как удалить точку?

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, хорошо подметили, спасибо

Comment: @АнтонКобелев, обновил, можно улучшить, конечно, ибо всё на коленке

Comment: @meine, большое спасибо!

Comment: @АнтонКобелев, слева от ответа есть галочка, поставьте её, если данный ответ решил вашу проблему